# Separate Exports from a MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I would like to create separate exported reports for the different types of animal I have in my table.  I can write these reports separately, however I have over 200 different animal types and therefore running 200 separate queries is impractical.

```
ANIMAL_TABLE

    AnimalName
    -----------
    CAT 
    DOG
    MOUSE
    HORSE
```

I basically would like to run a similar query to

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/ANIMAL-NAME.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY ‘\\’
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM ANIMAL_TABLE WHERE 1
```

but have 4 CSV files instead of one, effectively every change in animal type creates a new file

```
CAT.csv 
DOG.csv
MOUSE.csv
HORSE.csv
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know you've used it all the way through, but calling a column or variable `ANIMAIL` to represent **animals** is going to cause typos somewhere in the future!

Comment: I'm kind of curious how the mailman is going to stuff that horse into your postbox.

Comment: apologies, spelling checked and more details added.  Thank you for the pointing it out.  As for mailing the horse I am going the postman to try tail first ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/ANIMAL-HORSE.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY ‘\\’
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM ANIMAL_TABLE WHERE animal_name LIKE 'horse'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, I have over 200 different animal types and therefore running 200 separate queries is impractical.

Comment: You will have to build your query using dynamic sql not a terribly difficult task. Just build the elements using table query and a bit of string concatination rhen use the result as input for a query rince and repeat